# How to apply DynamoDB Query/Scan using FilterExpression for nested Json attributes in PHP

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

```
Record1: [{
"business_id": 2,
"forms": {
    "f522": {
        "id": "f522",
        "is_deleted": 0,
        "title": "Form 1"
        },
    "f8b6": {
        "id": "f8b6",
        "is_deleted": 0,
        "title": "Form 2" 
       },
    "fw56": {
        "id": "fw56",
        "is_deleted": 0,
        "title": "Form 3" 
      }
}
}]

Record2: [{
"business_id": 3,
"forms": {
    "f788": {
        "id": "f788",
        "is_deleted": 0,
        "title": "Form 11"
    },
    "f6yy": {
        "id": "f6yy",
        "is_deleted": 0,
        "title": "Form 12"
    },
    "f00i": {
        "id": "f00i",
        "is_deleted": 0,
        "title": "Form 13"
    }
}
}]

Record3: [{
"business_id": 4,
"forms": {
    "f839": {
        "id": "f839",
        "is_deleted": 0,
        "title": "Form 21"
    },
    "f1bc": {
        "id": "f1bc",
        "is_deleted": 0,
        "title": "Form 22"
    },
    "f6ac": {
        "id": "f6ac",
        "is_deleted": 0,
        "title": "Form 23"
    }
}
}]
```

I have 3 records stored in dynamoDB table. Hash Key is business_id. forms object is parent object with child objects(id, is_deleted, title). I don't know business_id value. But i have only id value "f6yy". I want whole records with business_id using child object id(value is f6yy).  Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The below filter expression should work.

Filter expression on **JavaScript:-**

```
FilterExpression : 'forms.f6yy.id = :formIdVal',
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {           
        ':formIdVal' : 'f6yy'
    }
```

**PHP:-**

```
'FilterExpression' => 'forms.f6yy.id = :formIdVal',
```